# Is it possible to track the number of times a Gitlab CI Job is run?

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

I am new to Gitlab CICD. I am trying to automate my android versionCode.

I have a job which lets say "deploy". I was wondering whether I could have the number of times this job run.

This would allow me to have a number to use as the android versionCode.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` in [Predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

> The unique id of the current pipeline scoped to project

Comment: I already did but that tracks the times that the pipeline runs. Not just the job. so even when the specific job i want to track is not invoked, `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` still increments.

Comment: You could use $CI_JOB_ID but it gets big increments depending on other jobs on the server, not just +1.

Comment: Alternatively you'd have to DIY. For example store this number in some kind of external db, e.g. Redis. And then read and update it in your job.

Comment: You can even go crazy and use GitLab itself for such storage - define your var in Project Settings > CI/CD >  Variables, and then use API to increment it: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable

Comment: That would make things more complicated. Id rather look for a different way.

Comment: Well, with GitLab API it's just 1 line to `curl` it. But let me know if you find more natural way.

Comment: the thing is i dont know how reliable that API call is. What happens if it fails. Then the failed increment will cause problems.